# How to upgrade SonarQube from 3.5 to 5.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

I'm planing to upgrade my SonarQube server from version 3.5 to 5.1. I have took the database backup. I have some questions to be answered before upgrading. That's why I' here.

Question1 : Actually is it possible to upgrade from 3.5 to 5.1(It seems a big deference between these two versions).

Question2 : What are the things I should do before upgrading except database backup

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Follow the guide: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading

And nope you can't upgrade directly from 3.5 to 5.1. As per aforementioned guide:

> Nevertheless, if in your migration path you have an LTS version, you must first migrate to this LTS and then migrate to your expected version.

So you'll have to do a mid-stop at SonarQube 4.5.7 (versions are listed [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/)).

P.S.: 5.1 really is a sub-optimal choice for upgrading, it's an intermediary version known for having performance issues. Suggest you use the [latest instead](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) (note that 5.5 is just around the corner, the next L.T.S. being 5.6).